# replace specific tr content using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a table as the following:

```
<table>
    <tr>...<tr>
    <tr>...<tr>
    <tr class="replace">...<tr>
    <tr class="replace">...<tr>
    <tr class="replace">...<tr>
    <tr>...<tr>
    <tr>...<tr>
</table>
```

Using jQuery and AJAX, I want to replace the content of all the `<tr>` with the class name "replace."

Comment: got my solution, the use of tbody :D

Answer (score 5):

Simply use jQuery's method **[.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**

```
$("tr.replace").html('<td>New content comes here</td>');
```

Answer (score 0):

Like that for example:

```
$('table tr.replace').each(function(){
   $(this).html('New Content');
});
```

Reference: [here](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

Comment: You right html() should work too - i simply used to write it like this.

Comment: the <tr> with class="replace" is generated dynamically. in my ajax i have, another loops of <tr> to update those previousely there. this isn't working.

Comment: @user1021350 Maybe the problem is with the way you're trying to use it.

Answer (score -1):

```
$(".replace").each(function() { 
    $(this).html("your content here"); 
});
```

This will replace the content of all tr elements with the class replace. If you want to put different content in each tr, you should make the classes unique by add a counter to the class, for example replace1, replace2, etc.

The selector would then change into `$("[class^='replace']")`.

Comment: the <tr> with class="replace" is generated dynamically. in my ajax i have, another loops of <tr> to update those previousely there. this isn't working.

Comment: `.each()` is becoming a disease that cannot be cured.